# HTML Source from Browser Field in BlackBerry

Tags: html, blackberry, browserfield

How can I get the page source of a web page in a `BrowserField` inside a BlackBerry application?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the **Alt** key and type **RBVS**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to get this programatically. While one page redirects to other, I need to get the html content through the code. Any help would be much appreciated...